# Having trouble putting my header back on my CSV file

Tags: arrays, ruby, file, csv

Here is my code:

```
require 'CSV'

contents = CSV.read('/Users/namename/Desktop/test.csv')
arr = []
first_row = contents[0]
contents.shift

contents.each do |row|
  if row[12].to_s =~ /PO Box/i or row[12].to_s =~ /^[[:digit:]]/
    #File.open('out.csv','a').puts('"'+row.join('","')+'"')
    arr << row
  else
    row[12], row[13] = row[13], row[12]
    #File.open('out.csv','a').puts('"'+row.join('","')+'"')
    arr << row
  end
end

arr.unshift(first_row)

arr.each do |row|
  File.open('out.csv', 'a').puts('"' + row.join('","') + '"')
end
```

First I `.shift` so that my header fields don't catch the pattern (and ultimately swap) in the first conditional of the first `.each` loop. Then I conditionally swap cell values that match the pattern, and then store the correctly shifted values in an array. After this, I `.unshift` to attempt to put back my header fields I stored in `first_row`, but when I view the resulting `out.csv` file I get all my headers in the middle. Why?

Example data:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e1017d3ba81634d9e1227e7fe49536cb

Comment: Please edit your post to include an example of the data you're working with.

Comment: @Jordan, see edit please.

Comment: I'm glad my answer helped solve your problem. One last note unrelated to CSV: When you use [`File.open`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/File.html#method-c-open) you need to make sure the file is closed when you're done with it. The easiest way is to use the block form, as in my answer, which will close the file automatically. Otherwise you have to call [`close`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/IO.html#method-i-close) on the File object returned by `File.open`. You should do it in an `ensure` block so that it happens even if there are errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root of your problem is that you're not using the features provided by the CSV module.

First, `CSV.read` takes a `:headers` option that will catch the headers for you so you don't have to worry about them and, as a bonus, lets you access fields by header name instead of numeric index (handy if the CSV fields' order is changed). With the `:headers` option, `CSV.read` returns a CSV::Table object, which has another benefit I'll discuss in a moment.

Second, you're generating your own faux-CSV output instead of letting the CSV module do it. This, in particular, is needless and dangerous:

```
...puts('"' + row.join('","') + '"')
```

If any of your column values has quotation marks or newlines, which need to be escaped, this will fail, badly. You could use [`CSV.generate_line(row)`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-generate_line) instead, but you don't need to if you've used the `headers:` option above. Like I said, it returns a [CSV::Table](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Table.html) object, which has a [`to_csv`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Table.html#method-i-to_csv) method, and that method accepts a `:force_quotes` option. That will quote every field just like you want—and, more importantly, safely.

Armed with the above knowledge, the code becomes much saner:

```
require "csv"

contents = CSV.read('/Users/namename/Desktop/test.csv', headers: true)

contents.each do |row|
  next unless row["DetailActiveAddressLine1"] =~ /PO Box|^[[:digit:]]/i

  row["DetailActiveAddressLine1"], row["DetailActiveAddressLine2"] =
    row["DetailActiveAddressLine2"], row["DetailActiveAddressLine1"]
end

File.open('out.csv', 'a') do |file|
  file.write(contents.to_csv(force_quotes: true))
end
```

If you'd like, you can see a version of the code in action (without file access, of course) on Ideone: http://ideone.com/IkdCpb